# Pass components into page context with createPage

Tags: gatsby

I am building a theme that will dynamically decide what component to use for the header and footer of each page, and I want to pass a `getHeader` and `getFooter` function into the page context during the `createPages` build step, which can return the correct components to use for the header and footer on that page.

I don't want to use my own layout wrapper component, because I want this to happen one level lower. I basically want my `gatsby-node.js` logic to decide what header and footer to use for each page, rather than a global layout component.

Example within the `createPages` function of `gatsby-node.js`:

```
// ...
// Logic here will decide what component to use for the page template,
// as well as what header and footer component to use.
// ...

createPage({
  path: '/foo',
  component: 'component/path.js',
  context: {
    getHeader: () => {
      // return the header component that was decided for this page?
    },
    getFooter: () => {
      // return the footer component that was decided for this page?
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible to load the component during the node.js build phase and pass it into the page via context like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

---

Long answer: I would suggest a couple of approaches that may fit your requirements:

You can't trigger directly a function inside a `createPage` API, however, you can execute it outside the function (but inside the loop):

```
  queryResults.data.allProducts.nodes.forEach(node => {
   let header = getHeader();
   let footer = getFooter();

    createPage({
      path: `/foo`,
      component: 'component/path.js',
      context: {
        header: header,
        footer: footer,
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Then, in your component you just need to get the context and manage the components based on their value:

```
function Product({ pageContext }) {
  const { header, footer } = pageContext

  console.log('I am your header', header)
  console.log('I am your footer', footer)


  return (
    <div>Hello!</div>
  )
}
```

Another approach (dirtiest) is just to pass `props` in each page you want to change the header/footer to render a different component in your `<Layout>`